# InputMismatchException happens when I ran jar from cmd and doesn't happen if run from idea

Tags: java, windows, io, java.util.scanner

In my main method I have following code fragment:

```
            try {
                select = scanner.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                scanner.next(); //we should read erroneous
                System.out.println("Error. Please input number.");
                continue;
            }
```

I make mvn clezan install -> go to target directory. and begin work with application
Actually I input number but in console I see following message:

```
D:\freelance\Новая папка\myrepository\target>java -jar palindrome-artifactId-1.0
-SNAPSHOT.jar
Please type your name:
u1
Please select menu item
1 - suggest word, 2 - change user, 3 - my score, 4 - my word list, 5 - records,
6 - exit
1
Error. Please input number.
Please select menu item
1 - suggest word, 2 - change user, 3 - my score, 4 - my word list, 5 - records,
6 - exit
```

when I invoke application from idea(choose main method) I don't see thi problem.

Please help to troubleshoot my poblem.

P.S.

full main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please type your name:");
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        scanner.useDelimiter("\n");
        String userName = scanner.next();
        Game game = new Game(userName);
        AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger();
        int select = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println("Please select menu item");
            System.out.println("1 - suggest word, 2 - change user, 3 - my score, 4 - my word list, 5 - records, 6 - exit");
            try {
                select = scanner.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                scanner.next(); //we should read erroneous
                System.out.println("Error. Please input number.");
                continue;
            }

            switch (select) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.print("Word:");
                    String word = scanner.next();
                    if (game.suggestWord(word)) {
                        System.out.println("Accepted: your score - " + game.getCurrentUserScore());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Rejected: Word already exists in your list or it is not palindrome");
                        System.out.println("Your score - " + game.getCurrentUserScore());
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.print("Name:");
                    String name = scanner.next();
                    game.changeUser(name);
                    System.out.println("User changed successfully. Your score - " + game.getCurrentUserScore());
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Your score - " + game.getCurrentUserScore());
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Accepted words:");
                    game.getCurrentUserAcceptedWords().forEach(System.out::println);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    atomicInteger.set(1);
                    game.getScores().forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("#" + atomicInteger.getAndIncrement() + ". name: " + k + " , score: " + v));
                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.println("Goodbye! thanks for the game");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("You selected nonexistent menu item. Please try one more time.");
            }

        } while (select != 6);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should put more of your source **in the question** - not a link. In particular, the definition and usage of the `Scanner` all the way to the snippet you have shown.

Comment: @RealSkeptic topic updated

Comment: OK. Are you working on Windows?

Comment: what input are you giving as your `userName`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes windows

Comment: @thegauravmahawar **u1** as you can see in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably your delimiter. It is looking for a `\n`, but on Windows, each line ends with `\r\n`. So the username you get is probably `"u1\r"` though you don't see the `\r` (check its length), and the number that you enter is read as `"1\r"`, which is not parsable as a number.

I guess the simulated console in your IDE interprets your pressing <kbd>return</kbd> as just `\n`, and that's why it works there.

So change your delimiter, instead of `\n`, to `\r?\n`. The delimiter is a regular expression, and this would mean "optional carriage return, followed by a linefeed".